# What would the value in cell A be, if cell B = 5 and Cell C = 7

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large complicated table that represents a matrix, and I am doing matrix multiplications with it.

I would like to be able to say: What if the cell value of 2 or 3 particular cells in this worksheet are of a particular value, What then would the cell value of another particular cell be?

This would allow me to treat my worksheet as a large multi-output function.

Is this possible without VBA?

Comment: yes, just change the values. If you are afraid you can't revert the changes, then just create a copy of your worksheet (or backup your original file).

Comment: That is not much of an answer is it?

Comment: No it isn't otherwise I would've posted it as an answer, not as a comment. The implicit question is: based on the details you've provided to your question, this solution could work too. If not, then please provide more details, and explain why this doesn't work.

Comment: It actually is, you need to do the calculation either way. Otherwise you won't know the value. So you might have a live data area and a test data area or similar but essentially you need some way to do the computation.

Comment: I need to be able to make a list of different values of the cell X, given different input values of the cells Y and Z ( and W, etc). Thus, I need to be able to treat a worksheet like a large function. I think what-if-analysis comes close, but I don't think it handels it perfectly, because it only takes 2 inputs.

Comment: Can you please share some example? Without it it's really difficult to help.

Comment: Can you give us some more information on what you're trying to do? Also, SUMPRODUCT is great for dot products

Answer (score 1):

Taking a semi-wild stab at your problem:

A1 = (IF AND(B1=5, C1=7),Equation for A1 with those conditions, A1 if those conditions aren't met)

Without more details, I can't give you anything more

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what [data tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-e95e2487-6ca6-4413-ad12-77542a5ea50b) are for.

> In a cell on the worksheet, enter the formula that refers to the two
>   input cells.
>
> In the following example, in which the formula's starting values are
>   entered in cells B3, B4, and B5, you type the formula
>   =PMT(B3/12,B4,-B5) in cell C2.
>
> Type one list of input values in the same column, below the formula.
>
> In this case, type the different interest rates in cells C3, C4, and
>   C5.
>
> Enter the second list in the same row as the formula, to its right.
>
> Type the loan terms (in months) in cells D2 and E2.
>
> Select the range of cells that contains the formula (C2), both the row
>   and column of values (C3:C5 and D2:E2), and the cells in which you
>   want the calculated values (D3:E5).
>
> In this case, select the range C2:E5.
>
> On the Data tab, in the Data Tools group or Forecast group (in Excel
>   2016), click What-If Analysis, and then click Data Table.
>
> In the Row input cell box, enter the reference to the input cell for
>   the input values in the row.  Type cell B4 in the Row input cell box.
>
> In the Column input cell box, enter the reference to the input cell
>   for the input values in the column.  Type B3 in the Column input cell
>   box.
>
> Click OK.